# how to insert text at the beginning of each paragraph in bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk, text-manipulation

I have a file with multiple paragraphs separated by blank line. Technically they are not paragraphs just sections of text separated by blank line.

I want to number the paragraphs so to speak by inserting a number in the first line of each line following a blank line. So if my file says:

```
This is text.
This is more text.
Even more text!

This is text in section two.
Some more text.
You get the point...
```

I want to make it say:

```
1This is text
this is more text
Even more text!

2This is text in section two.
Some more text.
You get the point...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with bash builtin commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

l=1                          # paragraph counter
echo -n $l                   # print paragraph counter without new line
while read x; do             # read current line from file, see last line
  if [[ $x == "" ]]; then    # empty line?
    echo                     # print empty line
    read x                   # read next line from file, see last line
    ((l++))                  # increment paragraph counter
    echo -n $l               # print paragraph counter without new line
  fi
  echo "$x"                  # print current line
done < file
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, using the shell for text-parsing is very slow and cumbersome. Here are some other options:

1. Perl in "paragraph mode"

   ```
   perl -00pe 's/^/$./' file
   ```

   #### Explanation

   The `-00` turns on paragraph mode where "lines" are defined by consecutive `\n\n`, paragraphs in other words. The `s/^/$./` will replace the start of the line (`^`) with the current "line" (paragraph) number `$.`. The `-p` tells perl to print each line of the input file after running the script given by `-e` on it.
2. Awk

   ```
   awk -vRS='\n\n' -vORS='\n\n' '{print NR$0}' file
   ```

   #### Explanation

   `-vRS='\n\n'` sets awk's record separator to consecutive newline characters. Like perl's paragraph mode, this makes it treat paragraphs as "lines". We then tell it to print the current line number (`NR`) and the current "line" `$0`. The `-vORS=` sets the output record separator to consecutive newlines so that paragraphs are separated by blank lines in the output as well. Note that this will add 2 empty lines at the end of the output. To avoid that, you can use `head`:

   ```
   awk -v RS='\n\n' -vORS='\n\n' '{print NR$0}' file | head -n -2
   ```

By way of comparison, here are the times that the various solutions took on my system when run on a 10M test file:

```
$ time a.sh > /dev/null ## a.sh is Cyrus's solution

real    0m1.419s
user    0m1.308s
sys     0m0.104s

$ time perl -00pe 's/^/$./' file  > /dev/null 

real    0m0.087s
user    0m0.084s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time awk -v RS='\n\n' -vORS='\n\n' '{print NR$0}' file | head -n -2 >/dev/null

real    0m0.074s
user    0m0.056s
sys     0m0.020s
```

As you can see above, both the perl and awk solutions are an order of magnitude faster than the shell approach.